# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'toarray'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
class aSDAE_module():        
    def get_middle_layer(self,aSDAE,train_user):
        middle=self.model.predict({'user_rating':aSDAE,'user_sideinformation':train_user},batch_size=self.batch_size)[2]
        return middle
   
alpha = asdae_module.get_middle_layer(R.toarray(),aSDAE.toarray())
```

This is my piece of code where I am stuck, and I don't know how to resolve the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./run.py", line 142, in <module>
    train_user=train_user, train_item=train_item, valid_user=valid_user, test_user=test_user, R=R)
    File "/home/hira/Desktop/PHD/PHDMF-master/asdae_models.py", line 52, in PHDMF
    alpha = asdae_module.get_middle_layer(R.toarray(),aSDAE.toarray())  
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'toarray'
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in type 'array' in python, it is not obvious what are you doing in asdae module, but you have to either change the implementation of asdae to work with list type object instead of an array or using Numpy library.

in order to converting list object to Numpy array you can do like this code:

```
import numpy as np
# converting aSDAE list to an array
aSDAE = np.array(aSDAE)
```

Comment: sir i updated code please check that may be you got what i am doind